# Data masking in the application layer on MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, data-masking

Is it possible use data masking in the application layer? There are users in the app and there is a users table that keeps records. My application connects to the database with a single dba user. I can make data masking in the MS SQL Database. But, How can I do data masking for each users records in the application layer?

Answer (score 0):

> But, How can I do data masking for each users records in the application layer?

You can [impersonate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/customizing-permissions-with-impersonation-in-sql-server) a different user to trigger Dynamic Data Masking, or configure the application to connect with a user that lacks the UNMASK permission.

Comment: Yeah, but that is not in the application layer ;)